# How to upgrade pyenv (macOS) such that a fresh .venv contains an up-to-date pip?

Tags: pip, python-venv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm trying to prevent this warning every time I create a fresh .venv:

```bash
> /Users/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m venv .venv

> . .venv/bin/activate

> pip install ipykernel  # or anything
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/pi/code/foo/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Somehow `pyenv` has populated my fresh .venv with an out-of-date pip.

If I execute the suggested command it will upgrade my .venv's pip. But I don't want to be doing that every time I create a .venv.

I figured this might fix it, but it doesn't:

```bash
> /Users/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.2.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.2.1
    Uninstalling pip-22.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.2.1
Successfully installed pip-22.2.2
```

What is actually happening when I execute the above command? I was expecting it to update the pip for the python version created/maintained by pyenv. Which it seems to be doing:

```bash
 pi@pPro18-4 ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0
> find . -name 'pip*'
./bin/pip3
./bin/pip
./bin/pip3.10
./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip
./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip-22.2.2.dist-info

 pi@pPro18-4 ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0
> ./bin/pip --version
pip 22.2.2 from /Users/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

So why isn't this pip getting copied into my .venv when I create it?

I thought that was the way .venv creation worked.

How to clean up my pyenv Python installation so that it spawns up-to-date .venvs?

EDIT:

Insight from #python on IRC/Libera:

> grym: I don't think you can; i just get in the habit of `python -m venv somevenv && somevenv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

> jinsun: `python -m venv --upgrade-deps .venv` is a simple solution if you were just annoying by the pip warning (...) it is updating the pip inside the venv, forget about the base python, I don't even have pip in the base python

Comment: Why not simply upgrade pip once venv is setuped? I assume pip is installed in whatever version was coupled with that particular version

Comment: That's what I currently do. But I create a lot of .venv-s. It would be cleaner practice to update the reference pip. I just can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I originally posted it as a comment, but was suggested to make it a proper answer.*

An easier approach is to use the `upgrade-deps` flag when you create a virtual environment. Like this:

```
python3 -m venv --upgrade-deps .venv
```

It was added on python3.9, and according to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments):

> --upgrade-deps
> Upgrade core dependencies (pip, setuptools) to the latest version in PyPI

So, in other words, it will install pip and upgrade right away.

Answer (score 3):

This is the use case for [pyenv-hooks](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/libexec/pyenv-hooks)

`pyenv-hooks` are scripts that are executed by `pyenv` whenever certain commands are run. You can create hooks for regular commands like: `exec`, `rehash`, `which`, but it can also be a plugin command, like `virtualenv`. The scripts can be written in any language.

Here is the [wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Authoring-plugins#pyenv-hooks) with official instructions.

You can have a hook by creating a script at the following location:

```
$PYENV_ROOT/pyenv.d/<hook-name>/<your-script-name>
```

For example, to create a hook that upgrades pip, create a new script within this path:

> `$PYENV_ROOT/pyenv.d/virtualenv/after.bash`

With contents:

```
after_virtualenv 'PYENV_VERSION="$VIRTUALENV_NAME" pyenv-exec pip install --upgrade pip'
```

`after_virtualenv` is the command that tells `pyenv` when to execute. First, it sets the `pyenv` version to the name of the `virtualenv` we just created. with the variable `$VIRTUALENV_NAME.` Then it upgrades `pip` itself.

More details [in this article](https://www.daan.fyi/writings/pyenv-hooks).

Comment: +1 and thanks for the intel. However I'm trying to fill a specific gap in my understanding. AFAIK creating a .venv copies files from a reference Python on the system. And I'm looking to upgrade the `pip` (and maybe other packages) on this reference Python, so that future spawned .venv-s are up-to-date.

Comment: you can try activating the venv and then upgrading pip

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing: from the question, "If I execute the suggested command it will upgrade my .venv's pip."

Comment: I've been searching everywhere, but I don't see a way to control the default initial pip version. Actually, it is not even the same version I currently have for that python install, it seems to be the fixed version that depends on the os version. What you can do, that is much easier, is to use --upgrade-deps, like this: `python3 -m venv --upgrade-deps .venv`. It will install pip and upgrade right away.

Comment: Rodriguez (SO: why can I not nick-autocomplete/hilight) -- maybe you would care to put this as an answer. As I'm constantly creating .venv-s (to the point I have a shortcut in my .bash_profile for it), I'm going with this solution.